# How to fetch mp3 duration from rails active storage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rss, feed

I want to create an RSS feed for my rails app and submit it to iTunes and other services. One of the values Apple uses is:

```
<itunes:duration>DURATION H:MM:SS</itunes:duration>
```

How can I fetch it from a mp3 file stored on the Amazon cloud via Active Storage?

Thank you.

Comment: You should look into a process where upon upload of a new mp3, a few parameters are derived from the file (a.o. the duration), like when uploading images, upon upload the thumbnails are also generated. For already uploaded files you will have to create a script/task to download them, determine the duration, and update an attribute in the database (I think it is way too costly to do this on-the-fly). Do you know how to get the duration from an mp3 file? Check mp3 related gems: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=mp3

Comment: @pawciorr - Have you tried any of the libraries suggested above ?

Answer (score 2):

[taglib-ruby](https://github.com/robinst/taglib-ruby) can provide the information you are looking for. Look at its documentation on how to install it.

Make sure the gem and its required system dependency [taglib](https://taglib.org/) are installed.
Download the file from its source url and save it in `Rails.root/tmp` directory. (Assuming you can get the url the file it at and its stored in a variable `source_url`)

```
target_path = 'tmp/downloaded_audio.mp3'

IO.copy_stream(open(source_url), target_path) # download the source file

TagLib::FileRef.open(target_path) do |f|
 t = f.audio_properties.length_in_seconds
 duration_str =  (t/3600).to_i.to_s.rjust(2,'0') + ":"+Time.at(t).utc.strftime("%M:%S")
end
```

`duration_str` if the value you are looking for. You should ideally store it in your database so that you can use it whenever you generate your RSS feed.

Comment: Thank you Alok, I will try to use your suggestion and let you know if it works.